# How to run a .nb file in another notebook file changing a variable in a specific range

Tags: import, notebooks

Let's say I have a .nb file (called "File1.nb" ) in which some calculations are performed and the results can be exported. In that file all the variables are defined with the exception of the variable k .
In another .nb file I can define the value of k and then import and run File1.nb doing something like

```
FileToEvaluate = NotebookOpen["Directory...\\File1.nb"];

SelectionMove[FileToEvaluate, All, Notebook];

k = 82;

SelectionEvaluate[FileToEvaluate];
```

This code seems to work perfectly and for k=82 i can obtain the results that I want. Moreover I have to specify that the last line of File1.nb is

```
NotebookClose[FileToEvaluate]
```

so that File1.nb closes itself once it has finished running.

Now assume that i want to do the same operation many times, changing every time the value of k from 0 up to 100 (of course, k ∈ Integers ).
I tried with something like

```
For[k = 0, k < 101, k++, SelectionEvaluate[FileToEvaluate]]
```

but i can get just the results for the case k=101. 
I also tried to delete the line

```
NotebookClose[FileToEvaluate]
```

from File1.nb , but the result is exactly the same.

Does anyone have ideas to fix the problem and run File1.nb with different values of k without changing it manually?

Comment: Use `SelectionMove` to move to the cell where `k = 82`, then `NotebookDelete` the cell and `NotebookWrite` the new cell.  Then select the whole notebook and evaluate. Repeat.

Comment: Sorry, I have not understood properly that method....How can i fix the problem in this way? remember that i don't want to change every time the values of k manually

Comment: I think you just need to put `SelectionNotebook[FileToEvaluate,All,Notebook]` inside the loop, as `SelectionEvaluate` removes the selection when it's done

Comment: Could you not just the two .nb files simultaneously? the variables will transfer across notebooks within that session?